# How can I create a 'double shadow' effect?

Tags: photoshop-effects, background

I'm a newbie. I want to ask how to create a double shadow like this:

[image]

I don't know how it's called!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd maybe call it a "realistic shadow".

This is how you can do it:

- Start with a rectangular shape
- Apply a gaussian blur filter (filter -> blur -> gaussian blur)
- Select the warp tool (edit -> transform -> warp) and move around the points on the sides
- Add a mask (or rectangular shape) to cover the top part.

[image]

Comment: Thank to you, I've found this http://studentwebhosting.com/tutorials/design-realistic-box-shadows-in-photoshop/
I think It should be called exactly "realistic box shadow".